# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I'm getting the following error when I'm loading tidyverse. It was all working fine 
 a few minutes ago when I was running my shinyapp. How should I resolve this?

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in
>   loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): 
>   namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.1 is required

Comment: hi, try to uninstall and reinstall the `rlang` package.
Also check your libray paths. You can do so by typing `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Sure, thanks much. That worked.

Comment: Make sure that another R process/session that has the package loaded isn't running at the same time you're trying to reinstall the same package.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem but managed to tackle it. You may remove the current version of rlang using the following command:

```
remove.packages("rlang")
```

and then install the rlang again:

```
install.packages("rlang")
```

After that run the library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Comment: This worked nicely for me!

Comment: This didn't work in my case.

Comment: Worked thanks. Jesus. what a sh1t show. I'll be glad in the near future when all this grunt work will be taken care of by AI agents.  That day can't come soon enough.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this same problem and restarted R session and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to unloading and reloading rlang,

Click on Tools in the tab and check for Package Updates to update tidyverse

Comment: Rather than submitting a new answer, this suggestion would be more appropriate as a comment on another answer.

Comment: 10 reputation is required to leave a comment; Ibrahim doesn't currently have that option

Answer (score 2):

Also had similar problem but resolved it after a struggle. I used:-

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyverse")
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the similar problem.

The error could translate into understandable English as:

package 'rlang' version 0.3.0.1 is loaded into R successfully, but the other package that based on 'ralng' required a higher version (at least 0.3.1).

So that manually `install.packages('rlang')` will update the latest appropriate package 'rlang'

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be late answer,but I had the same issue and I fixed it by updating the packages, specifically : ggplot2, scales. according to this Rstudio [site](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problems-with-tidyverse-load-error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-tidyverse-in-loadnamespace-i-c-lib-loc-libpaths-versioncheck-vi-i-namespace-scales-0-4-0-is-already-loaded-but-0-4-1-is-required/3414)

Answer (score 1):

Start with `install.packages("devtools")` then `install.packages("rlang")`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, but none of the solutions mentioned above worked. Instead, I resolved it by manually removing the '*cli*' module, which was causing the error, from the folder where my packages for the version of R that I was using installed.
You can use `.libPaths()` to help locate the directory where the packages are installed.