# rtudio docker tidyverse not loading

Tags: docker, tidyverse, officer

I am running docker rstudio with

```
docker build -t rstudio .
docker run -dp 8787:8787 rstudio
```

and encounter this error when attempting to install and load `tidyverse` and `officer`:

here is the error from tidyverse:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2/libs/xml2.so':
  libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was able to install the library successfully with the following result, but still received the above error

```
> install.packages("tidyverse", dependenicies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 425161 bytes (415 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 415 KB

* installing *binary* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
* DONE (tidyverse)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp3uBCGG/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried suggestions from [Error trying to use the tidyverse library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61121561/error-trying-to-use-the-tidyverse-library) to no avail.

any other suggestions?

Comment: could you please clarify your question a bit? the error is only shown for ```officer``` but does it also occur for ```tidyverse```? and the second codeblock is about installing ```tidyverse``` is that from the suggestion you linked, or from your session?

Comment: I get the erorr for both tidyverse and officer. will make it more clear