# Install/Compiling Errors with R Packages: tidyverse and caret

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-caret

**I recently had to install RStudio and the R language onto a new Macbook. It seemed to install the packages normally but when I started run some newly written code, the console would not execute tidyverse and caret even though it said it was downloaded. This is what shows up in the console and it's the same messages for both caret and tidyverse:**

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/tidyverse_1.3.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 421072 bytes (411 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 411 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in

/var/folders/pl/w9k_0l4d4snfgcv53rp2t_4m0000gn/T//RtmpWScbjK/downloaded_packages

> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

I even tried to install it on just R and not RStudio too and This is the message that comes up for both tidyverse and caret when I try to install Rcpp both ways on just R and RStudio:

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary  source needs_compilation
Rcpp 1.0.8.2 1.0.8.3              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.8.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3086192 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/pl/w9k_0l4d4snfgcv53rp2t_4m0000gn/T/Rtmp53AysU/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong and I'm not seeing any solution on here or other sites that are working for me, I'd appreciate any help with this since I use R alot. If more info is needed please comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to reinstall the `rlang` package. You can use this code to reinstall this package:

```
remove.packages("rlang")
install.packages("rlang")
```

After that you can load the packages `tidyverse` and `caret` again:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
```

Check this question for more info: [Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415631/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-tidyverse-in-loadnamespace)