# I am Trying to run (tidyverse) in R studio but it is not working so what would I do?

Tags: r

library("tidyverse")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.8 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required

Comment: `install.packages('vctrs')` and try again

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451908/tidyverse-not-loaded-it-says-namespace-vctrs-0-2-0-is-already-loaded-but or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415631/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-tidyverse-in-loadnamespace

Comment: If the package it already loaded, you'll probably want to restart your R session first, and then run `install.packages('vctrs')`

Comment: thank u,  let me try

Comment: After installing this , it is showing this error, what would I do next......                                        library("tidyverse")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required