# Why do I get this error when loading library tidyverse?

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

Yesterday I loaded tidyverse` as usual, but not I get the following error:

`library(tidyverse)`

`Warning: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.1.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.1 is required`

I already updated my packages.

Also, I have tried the following:

```
remove.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("tidyverse")
remove.packages("rlang")
install.packages("rlang")
```

But again, when I load `library(tidverse)` I get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415631/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-tidyverse-in-loadnamespace)

Comment: I already did that, but I'm getting the very same error.

Comment: Same with package `formattable`: 
`Warning: package ‘formattable’ was built under R version 4.1.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘formattable’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required`

Comment: Try to restart your R session and reinstall both packages

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: Can you update your post with the list of things you've tried and the errors you encounter at each step? It will be easier to help you if you provide more information

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I updated my `R` version (to 4.2.2) and changed it to RStudio manually: Tools -> Global Options -> R version.