# loading library (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I am trying to load tidyverse, it is throwing this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:  .onAttach
> failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:   call: NULL
> error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘cli’ 3.6.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required

It was working all fine but could not find the function "pivot_longer". I googled, tried to update all the packages, checked for dependencies, installed vctrs. It still didn't work. Closed the R session, restarted and tried to load tidyverse. it gave me an error:

> fatal error: unexpected exception: Bad allocation.

I terminated the session again, downloaded my material and re-run the entire R studio. It started giving me this error when I am loading tidyverse:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:  .onAttach
> failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:   call: NULL
> error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘cli’ 3.6.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required

Comment: It looks like `packageVersion('cli')` is 3.6.0, but is not sufficient for tidyverse packages that depend on it. Can you try to update the package? Try running `install.packages('cli')` (this may require updating other packages) and afterwards check the version of `cli`.

Comment: What @LMc said, but make sure you are in a fresh session with nothing loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415631/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-tidyverse-in-loadnamespace)

Comment: I did install.packages("cli) and the version is 3.6.1. Now when I tried loading tidyverse, R session aborted and restarted. i tried tidyverse again and this time it threw this error:Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘xfun’ 0.36 is being loaded, but >= 0.39 is required

Comment: Looks like I have resolved the issue (at least for now) by updating xfun. Able to load tidyverse and able to use pivot_longer function which I wasn't able to run today.